# broken print feature in python 2.7.11

Tags: python

A problem exists in Python `2.7.11`, with the print function:

```
elif e=="randomize w and x":

   random=randint(int(w),int(x))

   print random

elif e=="randomize w and y":

random=randint(int(w,int(y))
```

**print** random

The boldfaced print shows up as a syntax error, yet all 278 others in my program do not. Why this is, and how I fix it?

Comment: Given that this is a Python program, ensure that your code is properly formatted. It is often helpful to include the specific error you're getting. (Though I believe the answers to this question already have the right of it.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in

```
random=randint(int(w,int(y))
```

a close parenthesis after `w` is missing, therefore Python thinks the expression continues on next line, but `print` at that point is a syntax error.

Comment: thank you, In major amounts of copy, paste, change two or three variables in a long line I sometimes get mixed up, thx

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the print statement, rather the line right before it. The line before hass inbalanced parenthesis:

```
random=randint(int(w,int(y))
```

Make sure you balance them out (add an extra `)` at the end), and your error on the next line will disappear.